# vimscript: Is logical-or operator's two operands must stay in the same line?

Tags: vimscript

When I try to config my vim, I encounter something similar to below:

```
func! A_test_func(arg)
    if a:arg =~ '^.*[^i]ed$'
    \ || a:arg =~ '^.*[tk]s$'
        echo a:arg
    endif
endfunc

call A_test_func('works')
```

which results error:

```
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
```

I have read `:h E10`, and `:h line-continuation` then to make sure

```
set cp?     " echos `nocompatible`
set cpo?    " echos `cpoptions=aABceFs`
```

I also tried to put `||` at first line, error too.

Thus I wonder, is line-continuation forbidden for `||`?

Comment: Works for me. As in, it outputs `works`. Probably problem with encoding or line-endings?

Comment: make sure, that your `cp` and `cpo` setting is set before defining your function

Comment: @Christian Brabandt  Yes the culprit is indeed the `cpo` set after my `.vimrc`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The problem is indeed related to the order of `cpo` option setting.

```
:verb set cp?
nocompatible
    Last set from /etc/vimrc

:verb set cpo?
cpoptions=aABceFs
    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim

:scr
  1: /etc/vimrc
  7: ~/.vimrc
 37: /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim
```

Thanks to @muru, and @Christian Brabandt for pointing me towards the right course.